# VRAY for blender hangs on Linked models

Tags: rendering, linked-data

I'm trying to render a scene with VRAY for blender. The scene I'm rendering is a character that has been linked into the file. My material is a simple black and white shader setup to override the entire scene.

When I render, blender freezes up. VRAY never opens, and my RAM fills up (32gb). It never recovers and I have to force quit blender. I have experimented with a variety of settings and nothing helps. It has no trouble rendering new objects that I create in the scene. And if I Make Local > All on my character, then it renders it just fine (making anything less than All local and the problem persists.)

I've looked through VRAY for blender's forums and bug tracker, and also general google searches, and I cannot find anybody else mentioning this issue.

Any ideas? I'll do further experiments to see if I can pin down more details of the issue and update, but I wanted to get the question up. I cannot share the exact scene as its for a client, but I will see about re-creating the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably report this as a bug to Chaos Group.

They wrote the exporter and created the Blender build.